# Helm Deployment: Connecting Kubernetes to Postgres DB in Cloud SQL

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, kubernetes, google-cloud-sql, kubernetes-helm

So I am deploying my spring boot app using helm. I am following a pre-existing formula used by our company to try and accomplish this task, but for some reason I am unable.

my `postgresql-secrets.yml` file contains the following

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ template "codes-chart.fullname" . }}-postgresql
  labels:
    app: {{ template "codes-chart.name" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
data:
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: {{ .Values.secrets.springDatasourceUrl | b64enc }}
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: {{ .Values.secrets.springDatasourceUsername | b64enc}}
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: {{ .Values.secrets.springDatasourcePassword | b64enc}}
```

This picks up the values in the values.yaml file

```
secrets:
   springDatasourceUrl: PLACEHOLDER
   springDatasourceUsername: PLACEHOLDER
   springDatasourcePassword: PLACEHOLDER
```

The place holders are being overwritten in helm using a variable override in the environment.

the secrets are referenced in the `envFrom:` of the `codes-deployment.yaml`

```
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
              name: {{ template "codes-chart.fullname" . }}-application

            - secretRef:
              name: {{ template "codes-chart.fullname" . }}-postgresql
```

my helm file structure is as follows:

```
|helm
|-codes
|--configmaps
|---manifest
|----manifest-codes-configmap.yaml
|--templates
|---application-deploy-job.yaml
|---application-manifest-configmap.yaml
|---application-register-job.yaml
|---application-unregister-job.yaml
|---codes-application-configmap.yaml
|---codes-deployment.yaml
|---codes-hpa.yaml
|---codes-ingress.yaml
|---codes-service.yaml
|---postgresql-secret.yaml
|--values.yaml
|--Chart.yaml
```

The issues seems to be with the `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL`:
if i use the private ip of the cloudsql db, then it says it is not accepting connections

if i use the jdbc url format:

ex: `(jdbc:postgresql://google/<DATABASE_NAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user=<POSTGRESQL_USER_NAME>&password=<POSTGRESQL_USER_PASSWORD>)`

then I get an 403 authentication error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

403 Forbidden:

The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
The 403 for authenticated users with insufficient permissions.

403 indicates that the resource can not be provided. This may be because it is known that no level of authentication is sufficient, but it may be because the user is already authenticated and does not have authority.

Let me add some examples:

https://www.baeldung.com/kubernetes-helm

https://medium.com/zoom-techblog/from-zero-to-kubernetes-4fd354423e6a